# proper tooltip for long Options of Select in Ant Design (Antd)

Tags: javascript, css, antd

We have Select components of different props (tag/no tags, with/without scrollbars), now I want to add a tooltip to the right of the options, but I can not use Tooltip to wrap around Option which will cause errors. And when tags mode is on, the Tooltip will hover over the 'check' icon.

This is the best I can do without using fixed width of content divs.
https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-shirley-ss1or?

In my application I can use a boolean `isTag` to decide is tag mode is on and increment the width of content div, but I can not know whether the scrollbar is applied. I tried to get the ref of the dropdown menu or option div but failed.

We don't want to use 'title' because tooltip looks way better.
We don't want to use 'dropdownMatchSelectWidth' because some options could be super long.

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: You seem to have achieved what you set out to do in your codesandbox, no?

Comment: Right now the tooltip overlaps with the check icon / scrollbar / the right border of the dropdown menu. I want to make sure the tooltip floats consistently to the right of the dropdown menu (say 10px away) no matter the tags checked or not, w/o scrollbar, etc.

Comment: Hey, did you figure out the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap the value of the `Option` element in a `Tooltip` element, like this:

```
<Option value={value} key={key}>
  <Tooltip title="tooltip">
    {option}
  </Tooltip>
</Option>
```